# Python: Regex help

Tags: python, regex

```
str = "a\b\c\dsdf\matchthis\erwe.txt"
```

The last folder name.

Match "matchthis"

Comment: No need for regex; just use `str.split("\\")` or similar.

Comment: working with directories its better to use os.path instead of splitting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use `os.path.split(path)` since it's platform independent.  You'll have to call it twice to get the final directory:

```
path_file = "a\b\c\dsdf\matchthis\erwe.txt"
path, file = os.path.split(path_file)
path, dir = os.path.split(path)
```

Answer (score 3):

Without using regex, just do:

```
>>> import os
>>> my_str = "a/b/c/dsdf/matchthis/erwe.txt"
>>> my_dir_path = os.path.dirname(my_str)
>>> my_dir_path
'a/b/c/dsdf/matchthis'
>>> my_dir_name = os.path.basename(my_dir_path)
>>> my_dir_name
'matchthis'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> str = "a\\b\\c\\dsdf\\matchthis\\erwe.txt"
>>> str.split("\\")[-2]
'matchthis'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = "a\b\c\d\match\something.txt"
match = x.split('\\')[-2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> print re.match(r".*\\(.*)\\[^\\]*", r"a\b\c\dsdf\matchthis\erwe.txt").groups()
('matchthis',)
```

As @chrisaycock and @rafe-kettler pointed out.  Use the x.split(r'\') if you can.  It is way faster, readable and more pythonic.   If you really need a regex then use one.

EDIT:
Actually, os.path is best. Platform independent.  unix/windows etc.